# How to transform a JS array of strings into a union with io-ts?

Tags: javascript, typescript, union-types, fp-ts, io-ts-library

I'm using [io-ts](https://github.com/gcanti/io-ts) and i'm wondering if there's a way to turn an array of strings (literals) into a union of such literals. For example:

```js
export const CONTROLS = [
  "section",
  "text",
  "richtext",
  "number",
];

export const ControlType = t.union(
  // What to do here? Is this even possible? This is what came to mind but it's obviously wrong.
  // CONTROL_TYPES.map((type: string) => t.literal(type))
);
```

I don't know if this is possible but given that `io-ts` is just JS functions I don't see why not. I just don't know how.

The end result in this case should be (with io-ts):

```
export const ControlType = t.union(
  t.literal("section"),
  t.literal("text"),
  t.literal("richtext"),
  t.literal("number"),
);
```

Comment: what do you mean by the word "union"?

Comment: should've been more explicit, updated the question @dandavis

Comment: i don't do ts, but it looks like that could be  `t.union(... CONTROLS.map(t.literal));`, as long as t.literal just expects one argument, otherwise you need a map wrapper to call just one arg.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

io-ts formally recommends to use `keyof` for better performance with string literal unions. Thankfully, that also makes this problem much easier to solve:

```
export const CONTROLS = [
    "section",
    "text",
    "richtext",
    "number",
] as const;

function keyObject<T extends readonly string[]>(arr: T): { [K in T[number]]: null } {
    return Object.fromEntries(arr.map(v => [v, null])) as any
}

const ControlType = t.keyof(keyObject(CONTROLS))
```

Comment: This is what the code above for ControlType generates: ` t.KeyofC<{number: null, section: null, text: null, richtext: null}>`. 

Which is correct since it'll only get `keyOf`